# How To Have Margin For Background Image?

Tags: html, css, background

The following is the structure of the code of my website.

```
<body class="xxx">
    <div id="top-header">... code ...</div>
    <div id="wrapper">... code ...</div>
</body>
```

And this is the CSS code I use for a background image.

```
body {
    background-image: url('http://example.com/background-image.jpg');
    background-position: top right;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

The problem I have with this is, about 50px of the background image is hidden under the "top-header" div, which is 50px in height (It's the menu). How do I adjust the code so that the background image shows properly, fully below the menu (top-header)?

Just so, you know, I tried this css code as well:

```
#wrapper {
    background-image: url('http://example.com/background-image.jpg');
    background-position: top right;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

And this changed the white background of my content to the image. Which is not what I want.

The only way is to move the starting point of background-image 50px down. How do I define that? Please try help. Thanks.

Comment: I did not. The others did. I didn't realize my mistake until I found that this topic has been closed. I really don't know how I ended up here, when I logged into stackoverflow :(

Comment: I love it when people solve their own problems. So your nickname seems to be incorrect :-). Good luck and see you around.

Comment: @Gerben thanks for the kind words!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry guys, this was easy. I actually followed the CSS Twitter uses for background, and I got it. I just had to replace "top right" with "right 50px" where 50px is equal to the margin you'd like to leave at the top of the background image.

```
body {
    background-image: url('http://example.com/background-image.jpg');
    background-position: right 50px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

cheers!

Answer (score 1):

use this in style:

```
background-position: calc(100% - 30px) center;
```

example:

```
body {
    background-image: url('http://example.com/background-image.jpg');
    background-position: calc(100% - 30px) center;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

instead of 30px you can change the pixel value for positioning the background image.